# what are java executable format both in unix and windows

Tags: java, executable

I know about class/jar executable format. But jar/class can not ensure source security, because java source code(.java) can retrieve from it. I am looking for such a format where source are secure/un-retrievable.

Comment: Actually i have a job to develop online inventory and POS system. Main functionality will be in java or CPP and will call by a server side script(PHP/.NET)through shell command. In future a complete multi-user online office management system will be implemented in very similar way. We are preferring JAVA for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make code secure from reverse engineering.  If one has permission to execute it, then it can be examined where it can be disassembled, reverse compiled, or matched against known assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer can run it, then you can reverse-engineer it. There is no way to avoid this. The best you can hope for is to stop casual cracking by (for example) passing your source through an obfuscater before compiling.

IBM did this with their type-4 JDBC drivers and it makes it hellishly difficult to understand what's going on (right up until the point you write a program that can de-obfuscate it although you still need to add information back in like function and variable names, no easy task).

Security through obscurity never works against a determined foe. This is the same as with physical security. You can put as much security in your house as you like, and that will prevent casual break-ins, but it will not stop a determined burglar.

I would rather concentrate on doing what I do best, providing top-notch quality software. Most attempts to secure code (beyond simple obfuscation) almost always disadvantages your real customers more than your attackers. Is your code *really* so precious that you want to risk that?